# Page selector PHP

Tags: php

i need to be able to get the file name and the "page" variable in one string or something. Because i need to check if you come from index.php or another page. The problem with my code is that the statement will always be "true" because "$file" only contains the file name and not the file name and the $_GET variables e.g (index.php?page=news). Any ideas guys?

```
$file = mysql_real_escape_string(basename(__FILE__));

if ($file != "index.php")
    $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);

else
    $page = "index";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for `!empty($_GET["page"])` instead of `$file != "index.php"`.

Then you only set `$page` if there is also content in the parameter `page`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Querystring to the end of your $file var for comparison.  $_GET contains the querystring, and http_build_query() will turn it into a KVP format like "var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3":

```
$file = mysql_real_escape_string(basename(__FILE__)) .http_build_query($_GET);

if ($file != "index.php")
    $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);

else
    $page = "index";
```